# Evaluating a scalar product of a vector and a differential operator vector

Tags: operators

I created a scalar product of a vector $\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and of a vector consisting of a differential operators

```
op[t_] = (D[#, {t, 2}] - 3 D[#, t] + 2 #) &;   (1)
delop = {op[t], op[z]}; X = {1, -2};
```

I would like to apply this scalar product to a function and tried the following (not working solutions)

```
(X.delop)@Sin[t+z]    (2)
(X.delop) Sin[t+z]
```

leading to

```
((D[#1, {t, 2}] - 3 D[#1, t] + 2 #1 & ) - 2 (D[#1, {z, 2}] - 3 D[#1, z] + 2 #1 & ))[Sin[t + z]]
((D[#1, {t, 2}] - 3 D[#1, t] + 2 #1 & ) - 2 (D[#1, {z, 2}] - 3 D[#1, z] + 2 #1 & )) Sin[t + z]
```

How can I evaluate those expressions or directly obtain an evaluated expression in formula (2)?

Answer (score 1):

I would define "delop" as a function and do the scalar product after applying the function:

```
Clear["Globals`*"]
op[t_] = (D[#, {t, 2}] - 3 D[#, t] + 2 #) &;
delop[t_, z_] = {op[t][#], op[z][#]} &;
X = {1, -2};
X.(delop[t, z]@Sin[t + z])

(* -3 Cos[t + z] + Sin[t + z] - 2 (-3 Cos[t + z] + Sin[t + z]) *)
```

Note, the brackets are not necessary, due to preferences. I put them in to make the preference clear.

Comment: I get the error ```Set::write: Tag List in delop[t_, z_].... is Protected.```.

Comment: I think you already have somehow defined "delop" . I added "Clear["Globals`*"]"  to prevent this. Or try  a new kernel.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be a great solution as long as I have ```X.(delop[t, z]@Sin[t + z])```and not ```delop[t, z].X@Sin[t + z]```. Do you have a solution for the second scalar product as well to allow full flexibility in coding?

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider what you attempt in the second case is not proper syntax, which is why it does not work. It isn’t clear *why* you want to do that, or *what* you want to get. I suggest editing your question with such an alternative request, what the ideal outcome or intended goal is, and not what occurs when you try that syntax.